# ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm using https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-example-custom-shapes. I want to add two button click function in javascript (index.html) and function definition inside app.js.Result gives an error "function  is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick".

```js
<!-- javascript(app.js) -->

function load() {
    console.log('load clicked');
}
function save() {
    console.log('saved');
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML(index.html) -->

<body>
    <button onclick="load();">Load</button>
    <button onclick="save();">Save</button>
  <div id="canvas"></div>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: load() and save() are stored in app.js?

Comment: @NewToJS That is not true..

Comment: In the snippet, it is working fine.

Comment: you have two snippets and calling a function from another snippet won't work.

Comment: Your code seems fine, you must be using wrong path for `app.js`.

Comment: @PintuKumar you're correct i have modified its working fine

Comment: @PintuKumar path is correct.function is not triggering in app.js.

Comment: @MaheerAli error-Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: @user11479128 Put the script tag before the loading of buttons.

Comment: @MaheerAli  same error after putting the script tag above buttons

Answer (score 0):

This error happens, because your `<script src="./app.js"></script>` uses WRONG path, or your ./app.js just doesn't have code that you shown. Here's working snippet:

```js
/* JS file that you included in HTML MUST contain it */

function load() {
    console.log('load clicked');
}
function save() {
    console.log('saved');
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button onclick="load();">Load</button>
    <button onclick="save();">Save</button>
  <div id="canvas"></div>
  
  <!-- Replace this with correct path to your app.js file -->
  <script src="./app.js"></script>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>
```

Your snippet(s) doesn't work because you added JS and HTML as separate snippets. So simply key to fix it is use correct path.

Comment: Something MUST be wrong if it doesn't work. Can you provide your code (as repository or some .zip file) to let us spot the thing that doesn't work?